Does the property of a.s. continuous paths imply the existence of this limit?
Let $X$ be a process with a.s. continuous paths and $X_0 = 0$. In addition, $f(s):=P(X_t-X_s>0)$. I am wondering whether it is possible to have that $\lim_{s \rightarrow t ^-}f(s)$ does not exists.
Is somehow the existance of the leflt limit related to the property of a.s. continuous paths?
At first I thought that continuity in probability - not even a.s. continuous paths -  gives the existance of the limit - not just the existence of the left limit - but this is false (I explain later my thought). However, does it give at least existence of the left limit or is it irrelevant?
To explain why I thought that continuity in probability might imply the existence of the limit let us take $X$ to be a Brownian motion. Then $\lim_{s \rightarrow x }f(s) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0 }P(B_t>0)$. Since $B_t$ converges to $0$ in probability, it converges in distribution as well and the above limit should be equal to 0. However, the above limit does not exists (the left limit is equal to 1/2) as $(0,+\infty]$ is not a set of continuity for $\delta_0$.
Any thought regarding this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

You can consider a process whose path is deterministic and continuous, and which crosses between positive and negative in every interval $(t-\epsilon, t)$.
For example, let $t=1$. Let $X_s=(1-s)\sin(1/(1-s))$ for $0\leq s<1$, and $X_s=0$ for $s\geq 1$.
I'm not sure what the relevance of your condition $X_0=0$ is, but if you want that too, you can take instead $X_s=s(1-s)\sin(1/(1-s))$ for $0\leq s<1$.
Then every point $s$ has either
$P(X_t>X_s)=0$ or $P(X_t>X_s)=1$, and both cases
occur for $s$ arbitrarily close to the left of $1$. So your "left limit" does not exist.

Thank you very much!
